# Acceleration Power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, power

> *Suppose we have a trolley currently at rest at point A, but the motor switches on, so that it accelerates and reaches point B, at point B, the velocity is 5m/s, Distance of A-B is 10m, mass of the trolley is 12kg, find the power required.*

I attempt to work out like this:

Assume:
a=acceleration,
F=force acting on the trolley,
m=mass,
u=initial velocity,
v=final velocity,
s=distance traveled,
t=total time needed to travel from A to B,
P=power required

Therefore,
P=F(s/t)
 =m(a)(s/t)

also,
v^2-u^2=2(a)(s)
a=(v^2-u^2)/(2s)
 =(5^2-0)/(2x10)
 =1.25

find t:
v=u+at
t=(v-u)/a
 =(5-0)/1.25
 =4

Therefore,
P=12(1.25)(10/4)
 =37.5W

so power is 37.5W,
is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct. Let $a$ be acceleration; $F$ force; $m$ mass; $v_0$ initial velocity; $v_f$ final velocity; $P$ power required; $x$ distance travelled and $t$ time taken. Hence,
$$P=\frac{Fs}{t}=\frac{ma\ x}{t}$$
Then $a=\frac{v_f^2-v_0^2}{2x}=\frac{5^2-0^2}{2*10}=1.25\text{ m s}^{-2}$ and $t=\frac{2x}{v_0+v_f}=\frac{2*10}{0+5}=4\text{ s}$

Hence, power is given by:
$$P=\frac{ma\ x}{t}=\frac{12*1.25*10}{4}=150\text{ W}$$

Comment: thank you, but what is your time formula? I don't know how to find the time

Comment: It comes from $x=\frac{1}{2}(v_0+v_f)t$.